# Extend interface with changes to types

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

I'm trying to expand express Request. I was able to do it like that:

```
type UserData = Record<string, any>

declare global {
    namespace Express {
        export interface Request {
            user?: UserData
        }
    }
}
```

Now I have some middlewares/routes that are used after authentication so I would like to create a new type/interface that is similar to the above but makes the user non optional.

This is what I've tried:

```
export interface AuthenticatedRequest extends Omit<Request, 'user'> {
    user: UserData
}
```

When I change my route handler to the new interface I get an error:

```
const handler = (req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
   ...
};


TS2322: Type '(req: AuthenticatedRequest, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void' is not assignable to type 'RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>'.
  Types of parameters 'req' and 'req' are incompatible.
    Type 'Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs>' is not assignable to type 'AuthenticatedRequest'.
      Types of property 'user' are incompatible.
        Type 'Record<string, any> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'.
          Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'.
```

[here it is in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOQKYA8YDECuA7AYxmAjwBo4AlVARx1QGcYLKIcZUo4BfOAMygQQcAOQYwURgxEBuALAAoRTACeYVHACqDTgBEAhjH1wAvFVQFoAEwA8TKMDwBzCvrwqAfPKUKrFgDb6knBO-hAARvr+iIpwcHj6IIxg+gQaAKLoElIxCnFx4tDwjhxQfKka1HSM8Aix+XE4OlAA-ABcWs0GRt4N3PX9CoOKhbBwJZzlaXAAguwAFqh4xASGqFZV9ExwGBx4VgxwAPIgwDA2mzUUIk2cIh65jc0d2nqG+t7DCpZ42-NuVn8nFMcAAFJIaB05jBFstgKsOBtaFtmHBJAwOtQGJBfqgKHhdh00JhcIRiKQAJSmB51PJwH4MCBAgB0YSc4NozNuUApim43kUfHwRBIeHpkjWrHYwNBVNpcQZ8EE0q4ZilpVlvTRbFKzKcqBgoJEAHoRBR-vsgTz6pIYDgoGLlaVPkA)

I guess it happens because of how express mounts middlewares and handlers.
Is there a way to make it somehow?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce. See [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOQKYA8YDECuA7AYxmAjwBo4AlVARx1QGd4BfOAMyghDgHIMwojBjwDcAWABQkmAE8wqOAFUGqKABEAhjA1wAvFVQFoAEwA8TKMDwBzChrwyAfOKkTjhgDYbBcax4gARhoeiJJwcHgaIIxgGgQKAKLoAkKhEuHh-NDwVjCqbHEK1HSM8AhhGeE4KlAA-ABcSjWa2i6VzBUdEl2SWbBwufmFcACCODAAFqh4xARaqMbF9ExwGHl4xgxwAPIgwDCmS6UUPNWqPI5pVTWNyqotGi49EkZ4KxP2xh6qenAAFIIaI0xpNprN5otaMsYBRBAxGtQGJA3qgKHg1o00JhcIRiKQAJR6S7ldJwV4MCDfAB0-msANoVLOUHxkmYLiAA)

Comment: @slideshowp2 looks like you didn't integrated it with express, I've created a playground based on yours that reproduces the issue.

Comment: [see this playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgOQKYA8YDECuA7AYxmAjwBo4AlVARx1QGcYLKIcZUo4BfOAMygQQcAOQYwURgxEBuALAAoRTACeYVHACqDTgBEAhjH1wAvFVQFoAEwA8TKMDwBzCvrwqAfPKUKrFgDb6knBO-hAARvr+iIpwcHj6IIxg+gQaAKLoElIxCnFx4tDwjhxQfKka1HSM8Aix+XE4OlAA-ABcWs0GRt4N3PX9CoOKhbBwJZzlaXAAguwAFqh4xASGqFZV9ExwGBx4VgxwAPIgwDA2mzUUIk2cIh65jc0d2nqG+t7DCpZ42-NuVn8nFMcAAFJIaB05jBFstgKsOBtaFtmHBJAwOtQGJBfqgKHhdh00JhcIRiKQAJSmB51PJwH4MCBAgB0YSc4NozNuUApim43kUfHwRBIeHpkjWrHYwNBVNpcQZ8EE0q4ZilpVlvTRbFKzKcqBgoJEAHoRBR-vsgTz6pIYDgoGLlaVPkA)